# Do variables defined with const use up memory?

Tags: c++

I've been researching whether I should use macros or constants in C++. This question isn't about that, but one thing that I realized is that macros don't take up memory (because they just do a text replace during preprocessing). But do constants take up memory? I wasn't able to find a good answer to this.

Comment: Yes. There are just like normal variables but you can't change them (unless you cast away their const)

Comment: "It depends". If you can make something `constexpr`, use `constexpr`. If you can't, use `const`. If you can't, then use non-const. The compiler is smarter than us and also can neither feel pain nor fall in love, so some say it is the next step in evolution. Macros suffer from poor (no) type safety, but `constexpr` can give you those guarantees you crave.

Comment: *"macros don't take up memory"* -- hmm.. As a thought exercise (not a recommendation): if you start with `#define MACRO_ARY(name) long long name[1024]`, then add `MACRO_ARY(fee); MACRO_ARY(foo); MACRO_ARY(fum);`, you probably just increased your memory requirement by 192 kB. Is that consistent with what you mean by "don't take up memory"? The macro itself does not exist after pre-processing, even though its effects may live on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do variables defined with const use up memory?

As far as abstract machine is concerned, yes they do.

As for actual memory: Potentially, yes. Not necessarily. Same goes for non-const variables. If you can replace a constant with a macro, then such constant should be possible without using memory.

> I've been researching whether I should use macros or constants in C++.

Don't use macros. They do not respect namespaces and cause problems with name collisions.